# Directory Error when I package the spring boot project through 'maven-assembly-plugin'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin

I package the spring boot project through 'maven-assembly-plugin', but I get a Directory error.

Why the 'config' folder is in the root Directory, not in the 
 'bth_core' Directory?

Here is the pom.xml

```
<build>
<finalName>bth-core</finalName>
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>

        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude> **/assemble/**</exclude>
                    <exclude> **/properties/** </exclude>
                    <exclude> **/log4j.properties </exclude>
                    <exclude> **/script/**</exclude>
                      <exclude> **/spring/**</exclude>
                    <exclude> **/sqlmap/** </exclude>
                     <exclude> **/jobs/** </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>  <!-- mvn assembly:assembly-->
                <execution>
                    <id>make-zip</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors> 
                            <descriptor>src/main/resources/assemble/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the  assembly.xml

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>${mavenDir}-assembly</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
            <include>log4j.properties</include>
            <!-- <include>**/properties/${mavenDir}/**</include> -->
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/assemble/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/script/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/properties/*.properties</exclude>
            <exclude>**/key/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
    <!-- <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/properties/${mavenDir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>config/properties/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet> -->
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/log</directory>
        <outputDirectory>log</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>

    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/script</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>startup.sh</include>
        </includes>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/script/conf/setenv-${mavenDir}.conf</source>
        <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
        <destName>setenv.conf</destName>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
    </file>
</files>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven.wagon:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven.surefire:*</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.maven.plugins:*</exclude>
            <exclude>junit:*</exclude>
            <!-- <exclude>log4j:*</exclude> -->
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Comment: Don't use the assembly plugin, use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which packages it in the format needed for Spring Boot.

Comment: any demo? 
best regards

Comment: Remove what you have now and follow the reference guide, just add the plugin. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum thank you for  your suggestion.i had package my project through [spring-boot-maven-plugin]! but the app.properties  is packaged in jar! if i want to modify it ,i have to   type 'jar xf  projectName.jar'  to release the package,modify app.properties,and  compress again!That's very  troublesome,any solution?best regards

Comment: Why would yo need to modify the properties at all? That is something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. A change of properties means a new deliverable or simply externalize your properties if they change for different environments. You shouldn't be modifying the deliverable per environment as that basically is a new deliverable which you cannot guarantee is the same as before.

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum   ,thank you  for analyzing my question prudentially! let me tell you the my scene.the tester have to modify the corePoolSize of threadPoolTaskExecutor by himself , so that he can find out the  best performance before deliverable  product environment...

Comment: I would say that messing around with those settings on any environment that isn't the production environment is useless. However I would suggest externalizing the properties so that you don't have to create a new deliverable, just modify the properties and restart the application. If you are running an embedded server with Spring Boot (instead of deploying to a server) this is supported out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must, here's how I successfully used maven assembly plugin with spring boot maven plugin:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly_descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>  <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase>  <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

HTH :)